# Multiple measurements per person per treatment

Tags: statistics

Suppose I wish to assess reaction time of individuals before and after treatment.

Now to analyse the results I could use a paired t-test or if I had additional treatments, I could use a repeated measurements ANOVA. These approaches however assume that there is 1 measurement of reaction time per person, per treatment.

However suppose that for each individual, we measure their reaction time 5 times before treatment and 5 times after treatment. How should I adjust the t-test or repeated measurements ANOVA to account for this?

Comment: If you do not get an answer here, try also Cross Validated which specializes in statistics. Perhaps you should take the mean of the 5 treatments and treat it as one value.